# Debugging: Extra whitespaces at the end of a row JAVA

Tags: java, string, debugging, formatting, whitespace

I'm printing a 9 by 9 gridline structure of a Sudoku board and am getting two whitespaces at the end of each row - I do want to have two spaces in-between but not at the end. For example, my output right now is:

"2  5  3  6  7  9  1  8  4  "

When I'm looking for:

"2  5  3  6  7  9  1  8  4"

I tried to solve it through the if clause in the second for loop. Thank you in advance!

```
public String toString() {
    String sudokuString = "";
    int row;
    int col;
    
     
     for (row=0; row < 9; row++) {
        LinearNode<Integer> element = board[row];
        element = element.getNext();
        sudokuString+= element.getElement() + "  ";
        element = element.getNext();
            
           for (col=0; col < 9; col++) {
                while (element != null) {
                    sudokuString += element.getElement();
                    element = element.getNext();
                
                    if (col<8) {
                        sudokuString += "  ";
                    }
                }

            }
        if (row < 8) {
            sudokuString += "\n";
        }
    }

    return sudokuString;
}
```

Comment: You can use the substring() method to get rid of the last two spaces at the end.

Comment: *I tried to solve it through the if clause in the second for loop.* And?

Comment: @DavidLee Thanks for responding! I tried  implementing that both above the if statement and under the if statement, and it didn't seem to work with my string. i used sudokuString.substring(24); 24 includes all the numbers and double spaces in between

Comment: What resultant strings did you get with your original code and the one with substring()?

Comment: @DavidLee It ended up being the same result, so "2 5 3 6 7 9 1 8 4 " for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're getting extra space at the end of each row, give a condition while to block last space while adding it.

Here's sample code

```
public static String toString1() {
    String sudokuString = "";
    int row;
    int col;
    
    int[][] ar = new int[9][9];
    int counter = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++) ar[i][j] = (i+j) * ++counter;
    }
    
    for (row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            sudokuString += String.valueOf(ar[row][col]);
            
            if(col != 8) sudokuString += "," ;    // add " " instead of ","
        }
        
        if (row < 8) {
            sudokuString += "\n";
        }
    }

    return sudokuString;
}
```

I've used **','** instead of space (' ') for better understanding.